# How to load a smaller GPT2 model on HuggingFace?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I know I can load the smallest GPT2 variant using

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, AutoConfig

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=context_length,
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel(config)
model_size = sum(t.numel() for t in model.parameters())
print(f"GPT-2 size: {model_size/1000**2:.1f}M parameters")
>>> GPT-2 size: 124.2M parameters
```

But how can I load a GPT2 architecture with a smaller number of decoder layers? Say, 3 or 5 instead of the original (I think it's 12)? Note that I'm training this from scratch so I'm not looking for an already pretrained model.

Comment: It should be sufficient to specify `n_layer=3` or `n_layer=5` as an additional parameter to the `.from_pretrained()` method of the `AutoConfig` class (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.26.1/en/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2Config).

Comment: @amiola Amazing, didn't realized it's that simple. Thanks a lot! If you want to put this as an actual answer and not a comment I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stack 3 or 5 decoder layers rather than the default number of layers `gpt2` has (12) it is sufficient to pass either `n_layer=3` or `n_layer=5` as an additional parameter to `.from_pretrained()` method of the `AutoConfig` class ([`GPT2Config`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2Config) under the hood).

```
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=context_length,
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    n_layer=3
)
```

Alternatively, you can also pass `num_hidden_layers=3` or `num_hidden_layers=5`. Indeed, due to https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/13026, the two are interchangeable.

```
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=context_length,
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    num_hidden_layers=3
)
```